# rsync: how to handle backup to CIFS volume

Tags: rsync, cifs

I am backing up data from a GNU/Linux system to a CIFS mount. There are clear limitations to this, such as characters in filenames (eg. colons (:)) and symlinks not being supported by the destination Windows file system.

Rsync backup proceeds well enough using the following (note mirror backup):

```
rsync --bwlimit=62500 --log-file=${logfile} -av --no-links --delete ${src_dir} ${dest_dir}
```

Rsync reports errors on transferring file according to limitations above and returns error code:

> rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1052) [sender=3.0.9]

Issue is that I want ensure rsync completes successfully, **given the limitations of the destination file system**.

The error code reported appears to be too general (`code 23: Partial transfer due to error`) to just skip over in the wrapper `bash` script that checks the return code ie, if I skip over this error I may ignore a failed backup.

I have tried adding exclusion criteria to rsync, such as `--no-links --exclude='*:*'`, which does work on that specific case. However, this seems like a piece-meal solution as I would need to update this when new conditions arise that cause backup to fail due to destination file system incompatibilities.

I prefer not to `tar` backups as users require option to retrieve deleted files from backup.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging here is solution that works:

```
rsync --bwlimit=62500 --log-file=${logfile} -av -s --iconv=ISO-8859-1,utf-8 --no-links --delete ${src_dir} ${dest_dir}
```

Note the use of the `-s` and `--iconv=ISO-8859-1,utf-8` option which allows for spaces in filenames (`-s`) and converts filename characters from Linux filename encoding (**ISO-8859-1**) to Windows (**utf-8**), `--iconv=ISO-8859-1,utf-8`. Also note the use of `--no-links` as symlinks are not supported by destination filesystem.

Limit on bandwidth (`--bwlimit=62500`) is specific to my implementation as the transfer takes place over a 1Gbit link that shares user SSH traffic as well.

The Windows share is mounted using `mount.cifs` like so:

```
mount.cifs ${win_share} ${local_mount_point} -o gid=16000,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775,iocharset=utf8,cache=none,mapchars
```

Note the use of `mapchars` which enables the following (from `man mount.cifs`):

> **mapchars**
>
> Translate six of the seven reserved characters (not backslash, but including the colon, question mark, pipe,
>          asterik, greater than and less than characters) to the remap range (above 0xF000), which also allows the CIFS
>          client to recognize files created with such characters by Windows´s POSIX emulation. This can also be useful
>          when mounting to most versions of Samba (which also forbids creating and opening files whose names contain any
>          of these seven characters). This has no effect if the server does not support Unicode on the wire. Please note
>          that the files created with mapchars mount option may not be accessible if the share is mounted without that
>          option.

I have tested the requirement of `rsync` flags `--no-links` and `--iconv=ISO-8859-1,utf-8`, as well as the `mapchars` option for `mount.cifs`. All are required for `rsync` to return successful error code of `0`.

I will update this solution as I encounter filenames that break it.